# Using Vectors in recode function

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I am a fairly new user of R.
I am trying to recode a new variable that takes a particular value based on the value of another variable in the dataset. It is taking a lot of time to assign a value element-wise.

To give more context, the Question variable has a range of 25 serial numbers that range over 700 observations. The data is arranged with Q1 for the first 25 variables and so on...
The grade level vector consists of values that need to be attached with each question number, therefore a vector of 25 elements. This is how I would have to use the recode function, but is there a shorter and quicker way to do this? Please help

```
grade_level<-c(7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,6,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,8,8,8,8)
math08_0510<-math08_0510 %>% mutate(Grade_Level= recode(Question,"Q1"="7","Q2"="7","Q3"="7","Q4"="8","Q5"="8","Q6"="8",
                                                        "Q7"="8","Q8"="8","Q9"="8","Q10"="7","Q11"="8","Q12"="8","Q13"="8",
                                                        "Q14"="6","Q15"="8","Q16"="8","Q17"="8","Q18"="8","Q19"="8","Q20"="7",
                                                        "Q21"="7","Q22"="8","Q23"="8","Q24"="8","Q25"="8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use a named vector by `paste`ing the 'Q' with the sequence of 'grade_level'

```
names(grade_level) <- paste0("Q", seq_along(grade_level))
library(dplyr)
math08_0510 <- math08_0510 %>%
     mutate(Grade_Level= recode(Question,!!! grade_level))
```

-output

```
math08_0510
   Question Grade_Level
1       Q1           7
2      Q14           6
3       Q2           7
```

#### data

```
math08_0510 <- data.frame(Question = c("Q1", "Q14", "Q2"))
```